# Replacing app-scrollpos-control in Polymer 2.0

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-2.x

Polymer 2.0 withdraws app-scrollpos-control from the app-layout component. What can be used to replace this feature? Is there a scroll behavior that remembers scroll position through fragments?

Answer (score 0):

In the app-layout repo, https://github.com/PolymerElements/app-layout, The last bulllet mentions, "app-scrollpos-control has been removed from App Layout in favor of using multiple scrolling regions to preserve the scroll position. In terms of UX, document.rootScroller is a new web platform API that will allow non-document scroll to hide the address bar on mobile." That's probably a good place to start. Here's the link to the replacement => https://github.com/bokand/NonDocumentRootScroller